# NVidia and Wifi card driver problems in ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, drivers

I have a HP Pavilion ab219tx that came pre-installed with Windows 10. I tried installing Ubuntu, but I have two problems:

1. My Wifi Card (Realtek) doesn't seem to be compatible with Ubuntu.  I assume I can replace it with a compatible Wifi card.
2. My NVidia graphics card doesn't seem to have drivers for Ubuntu.  Does it make any sense to use Ubuntu with a graphics card that doesn't have drivers?

Comment: You can install drivers for both. But the question is too broad.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a problem. You will have to install the proprietary nvidia drivers for any nvidia card, they are not included in ubuntu. Same with most realtek wifi cards. My latop (which is running ubuntu 16.04) also has an nvidia graphics card and a realtek wifi card. My suggestion is, plug in your laptop to your router using a lan cable and install a wifi driver. Then you can go about configuring the other things.

For your nvidia card, you will also need nvidia prime after installing the driver. This will enable you to switch between the integrated graphics card and your nvidia card. Without prime, th OS will use your default graphics card, which will be the integrated one.